# Change the font path when using Font Awesome

Tags: css, font-awesome

It works when I have my CSS file and the font files in the same folder.

But when I put my font files in side a folder, I can't get my icons.

Here is my CSS code..

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        src: url(fontfile-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3);
        src: url(fontfile-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3) format('embedded-opentype')
        ,url(fontfile-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3) format('woff')
        ,url(fontfile-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3) format('truetype')
        ,url(fontfile-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular) format('svg');
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    .att {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
        .att-renren:before {
            content: "\f18b";
        }
```

And my folder structure...

CSS file

```
Content/themes/common.css
```

Font files

```
Content/themes/fonts/
```

Can I change the path of the font files in CSS??

Comment: take a good IDE, mark the @font-face { ... } press `ctrl+f`, replace `url(` with `url(../fonts/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can change,

1. Open your fontawasome css file.
2. Find fontface path and edit for all fonts types.

   ```
   @font-face{font-family:FontAwesome;src:url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3)
   ```

Answer (score 5):

### You can use `SASS` to override the default path

```
/* path must be relative from the location of the compiled CSS file;
   assuming you have copied the `webfonts directory into `assets` folder*/
$fa-font-path: "./assets/webfonts";

/* Importing FontAwesome SCSS from node modules*/
@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
```

Comment: Thanks for this little trick. To make it complete, the import of scss may be shortened as following for each line, 

`@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";`

and don't forget the `regular`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using FontAwesome 5 and Sass you just need to set the `$fa-font-path`:

```
$fa-font-path : 'assets/fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
```

As @MRP points out in the comments I didn't mention that you have to place it before you import FontAwesome otherwise you don't override the Sass default variable.

Comment: no, it's not working, I change $fa-font-path in my config file but it's not working unless I change in the _variables.scss which is a bad idea!

Comment: the placement matters, it should be before importing FontAwesome scss ;)